# What do farming cycles control?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

The Twisted League Hardcore Harvester relic said "Farming cycles occur every 1 minute instead of every 5 minutes". The Trailblazer League relic "Botanist" says similarly. Obviously this means that crops grow five times faster, but is there anything else controlled by farming cycles that will happen 5 times faster? Should I check my compost bins more often, for instance? What all is controlled by farming cycles?

Comment: I suspect that compost and weeds are impacted, but don't have hard evidence on that suspicion at this time. Random event research suggests that events may be impacted as well but I suspect that it will be impossible to prove that suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really have a great source on this except for personal experience from Twisted League, but as I recall, the things that are affected include:

- Weeds
- Plant growth cycles, naturally
- **Plant disease**; you only have one growth stage to apply plant cure, so that time will be shortened
- Compost bins
- Seedling growth after watering
- I'm unsure about fruit and berry regrowth but I suspect it is affected as well.

I don't think random events are directly affected; however, they tend to spawn when gaining experience and when teleporting or leaving an instance, so if you're doing those things more often because you're checking your crops, then they may be indirectly boosted.